# No query result when one of the columns used in the output never has a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I have a query where the output involves summing two columns. If either of the columns never has a value (given a set of filter criteria in the `where` clause), there is no result. Why?

Here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_HQn8l_b_6HKjoAC7ZR5B29rKokm8hxckxWIyg8V28/edit#gid=0).

`=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(B) where A = 'ard'",0)` -> result exists

`=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(C) where A = 'ard'",0)` -> no result

`=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(B) - sum(C) where A = 'ard'",0)` -> no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are used to an empty cell having a value of zero in other functions. However, `QUERY` acts uniquely from other functions. As currently set up, you are asking `QUERY` to subtract a *null string* from a number (i.e., to act on two different data types), and `QUERY` makes no assumptions about what those "should mean" (i.e., it is literal). This is the same reason `QUERY` only returns *one* data type (the most populous one) per column if there are mixed data types in that column.

One approach would be to pre-process the range and then use Col*x* notation:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:A,IF(B2:C="",0,B2:C)},"select sum(Col2) - sum(Col3) where Col1 = 'ard'",0))`

However, you'd be better of just using a function that *does* make the assumption that null means zero:

`=SUM(FILTER(B2:B-C2:C,A2:A="ard"))`

Comment: For what it's worth, the `filter` suggestion at the bottom doesn't work because I'm looking for a single result that sums up all of the cells, whereas `filter` produces one result per filtered row. The `arrayformula` suggestion likely works, though (haven't check it yet). Thanks!

Comment: Simple fix on the FILTER formula. See my updated formula above, which is simply wrapped in SUM( ).